# Is there a way to chain pure and IO functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, composition

I'm currently learning Haskell. I'm stuck while composing a few IO functions with pure functions (I'm not sure if that is possible using the structure I'm using).

I have included below the full toy code replicating my actual problem.

```
import Data.Function ((&))

data MyType = I Int | S String | B Bool deriving (Show)

debugPrint :: Bool -> MyType -> IO (Either String MyType)
debugPrint flag mt =
  if flag
    then do
      print mt
      return (Left "Debug mode: short circuiting further steps")
    else return (Right mt)

strToInt :: String -> Either String MyType
strToInt s =
  if sLen >= 10
    then Left "String is too long"
    else Right (I sLen)
  where
    sLen = length s

intToBool :: MyType -> Either String MyType
intToBool (I i) =
  if i <= 0
    then Left "Integer is <= 0"
    else Right (B (i > 5))
intToBool _ = undefined

boolToStr :: MyType -> Either String MyType
boolToStr (B b) =
  if not b
    then Left "True expected"
    else Right (S "Final output")
boolToStr _ = undefined


finalHandler :: Either String MyType -> IO ()
finalHandler (Left err) =  putStrLn $ "ERROR: " ++ err
finalHandler (Right myType) = print myType

main :: IO ()
main = do
  s <- getLine
  strToInt s
  (_) debugPrint True
  (_) intToBool
  (_) debugPrint True
  (_) boolToStr
  (_) debugPrint True
  & finalHandler
```

I have 3 questions about the above snippet.

- I would like to know if there are any predefined operators which can be used to chain the above functions in `main`.
- Is there a better way to represent the error flow in this code? If there is any `Left` value in the intermediate outputs, the control should jump to `finalHandler` and let it process the value.
- The main issue I'm dealing with is composing the function `debugPrint` with `strToInt s`.
  I want to pass the `Right` value to `debugPrint` and conditionally print it using the `flag` parameter and return the same value if it's not being printed.

Please ignore the undefined pattern matches as they are handled in my actual code.

I have tried using `bind`, `(>=>)` and `liftIO`. But I'm still not able to how the abstraction can be changed to improve the data flow in the snippet.

Comment: within any monad (including `IO` of course) you can call a pure function with `let`. For example, instead of `strToInt s` you shoud write `let my_int = strToInt s`. Now, the variable `my_int` is available within the `main` function.

Comment: Now, the whole error handling. There is a better way to do it, but since you are learning I'd recommend you to first just pattern match `Left` and `Right` for every call to a function returning `Either`. Probably you'll end up with a very nested-unidiomatic function if you do so. Afterwards, you should read about the `Either` monad which is nothing else that the pattern you describe: "After a `Left` just shortcircuit"

Comment: hint: since you already know about `(>=>)` , try to explore the error hadling issue using that operator ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways this can be done, including explicit pattern matching. And of course you can always define your on operators for any task. Both are perhaps a good exercise.

However, what I would consider an *idiomatic* solution is to let all the work be done by the monad chaining.

I don't know how deep you've learned about monad; suffice it to say that the “mon” refers to a sense of singularity. It means that *everything is one*, so to say. Ok, that was a very nebulous statement; in practice what you should remember is that to monadically chain functions/actions, the result (i.e. to the right of all `->`) needs to have the same outer type-constructor in all of them. You already know this with e.g. `IO Int` and `IO ()`, but it works just as well with any other monad.

So that's what you need to achieve here, and then you can just use the ordinary `>>=` / do block syntax. First you need to figure out what's an appropriate monad into which you can cast all those actions. The simplest option would actually be to just use `IO`, in which you can after all throw and catch *exceptions*. You could reqrite all of your functions to be in `IO` – this, again, is a useful exercise but not idiomatic.

A more discipled option is to have the error cases as an explicit *monad transformer* on top of `IO`. You might expect this to be called `EitherT`, which [indeed exists](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=EitherT), but the more commonly used version is called [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT). It's still the same, literally just a newtype wrapper around `m (Either e a)`, which is a generalized form of e.g. the `IO (Either String MyType)` you have in your code.

The point of this newtype wrapper is to avoid nesting `Either ...` inside of `IO ...` (two monads), and instead combining them both into a single monad, so again the old combinators can be used.

What you still need to get started is a way to lift your `Either ...` results into the `ExceptT` monad. The `transformers` library has [`except`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:except), which does exactly that.

For `debugPrint`, I would change the type right in its signature:

```
debugPrint :: Bool -> MyType -> ExceptT String IO MyType
```

For the others, I wouldn't change the type but instead wrap them in `except` when using them in `main`.

I leave the actual code as an exercise.